# Encriptación Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Realizar una función que permita cifrar y otra función que permita descifrar un mensaje con el siguiente método criptográfico, la función de cifrado debe recibir como parámetro el mensaje a cifrar y retornar el mensaje cifrado, la función de descifrado debe aceptar el mensaje cifrado y retornar el mensaje descifrado. Se disponen las letras del alfabeto original de izquierda a derecha, desde la a hasta a la m; luego se contínua la serie, de derecha a izquierda, de la n a la z, pero dispuestas en una hilera paralela a la anterior, y que van a corresponder a las letras del alfabeto cifrado. Por último para cifrar, se hace corresponder la letra superior con su correspondiente inferior, siendo esta última la que figura en el texto cifrado. Ejemplo: El mensaje firma la paz se convierte en URINZ AZ KZA

Answer (score 0):

para encriptar ingrese cualquier oración y el corrimiento puede ser cualquier numero entero. para volver a recuperar el mensaje cambie el el + por un - en la linea del comentario. luego vuelva a ejecutar el código ingrese el mensaje codificado y vuelva a ingresar el numero entero que uso para el corrimiento al momento de cifrar el mensaje

```
abecedario="abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwyz "
frase=input("frase a encriptar: ")
encriptada=""
while True:
    try:
        corrimiento=int(input("corrimiento: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("error! por favor ingrese un numero")
for caracter in frase:
    if caracter in abecedario:
        indice=abecedario.find(caracter)
        indice=(indice+corrimiento)%27 # para decencriptar cambiar el + por un -
        encriptada+=abecedario[indice]
    else:  
        encriptada+=caracter
print("texto encriptado:", encriptada)
```

este tipo de "encriptacion" se genera mediante un corrimiento dentro del abecedario. en tu pregunta no se sabe que tipo de corrimiento o que método se utilizo.

Comment: Se agradece la colaboración, pero StackOverflow no es una comunidad para resolver tareas. Por supuesto que se puede ayudar con problemas académicos, siempre que el usuario demuestre que está trabajando y que verdaderamente tiene problemas para avanzar, mostrando el código que no le está funcionando.

Comment: estoy completamente de acuerdo con vos. cual es mi inconveniente para poder comentar lo que dijiste me faltan 21 puntos no me queda otra que prestar el código para poder agregar lo que dijiste. si no agrego código me sacan puntos